# Create flowtype for React component with static fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I'm expecting React components like so:

```
class MySetting extends React.Component<{}> {
  static name = 'My Setting';

  render() {
    return (<div>{'setting here'}</div>);
  }
}

class Widget extends React.Component<{}> {
  static settings = [ MySetting ]

  render() {
    return (<div>{'widget here'}</div>);
  }
}
```

And I'd like to make a flow definition for them that essentially mean:

- A react component that has a static field `name`
- A react component that has a static field `settings` which is of the above type

How do I do this? I've tried a couple things like:

```
interface Settings {
  name: string;
}

export type SettingsComponent = React.ComponentType<Object> & Settings

interface Widget {
  settings: Array<SettingComponent>;
}

export type WidgetComponent = React.ComponentType<Object> & Widget
```

Or

```
declare class SettingsComponent<Props, State = void> extends React$Component<Props, State> {
  static name: string;
}

declare class WidgetComponent<Props, State = void> extends React$Component<Props, State> {
  static settings: Array<Class<SettingsComponent<any, any>>>
}
```

But they inevitably throw various flow errors that are awkward to decipher. Is there a generally accepted way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like with some more research I found a solution (using `flow-bin@0.63.1`).

The answer is flow's [`$Subtype<T>`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-subtype) utility type:

```
export type SettingsComponent = {
  name: string;
} & $Subtype<React.ComponentType<Object>>

export type VisualizationComponent = {
  settings: Array<SettingsComponent>;
} & $Subtype<React.ComponentType<Object>>
```

Though I'll add that while my previous flow errors are gone and errors do show up when using a component with missing static fields or accessing non-existent fields, my editor (Atom + Nuclide) doesn't show tooltips for the type anymore.